# Handle the button list in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I’m continuing to the last ViewController in my movie booking project. Because I’m new on iOS so please apologize if my question is so popular and very basic. Thank you in advance!.

So I have trouble to solve problem with the list of buttons in the cell.

E.g:

I have the swift class file for the button:

```
 class ButtonReverse: UIButton {

      require.init()
      //something here. Color, etc.
 }
 class TypeOfSeat {
      var normalSeat: Bool
      var coupleSeat: Bool
      var reversedSeat: Bool
      var reversingSeat: Bool

      // something here
 }
 class Total: TypeOfSeat {
      var priceOfSeat: Int
      func invoice () -> Int {
       /// something here to return total of invoice.
       // return total }
```

In the UITableViewCell.
I have list of the buttons to be ordered vertically.

How can I loop over the cell and create list of the buttons in one cell and random the button color that I have defined before be implement the function:

```
cellForRows at: IndexPath
```

[image]

All of buttons will be sorted in just one cell. Red is reversed seats. Yellow is reversing seat. And Green is available seat ready for reverse.

I have idea to use uicollectionview. But I want to use it with tableview only because i’m just starting with uitableview.

To handle the button in the cell I’m just using simple function to call delegate for UIAlert and show message: the seat is reversed or show the total......when user touch the button.

Many thanks,

Comment: You are right, using collection would be the better idea and its not too diff from tableView. All your button can be cells and this can be done easily.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with UICollectionView. Good hint!

Comment: Could you please answer the question with this solution? I’m so glad to mark your answer as the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you can follow these steps :

1. Use `CollectionView`.
2. Take your colors in an array and use `random` to get color randomly and make an array for your collection (say `dataArray`).
3. If you are using buttons just to click, then don't use them instead you can give cell's content view (or you can take one view in cell) `corner radius` to make them circle and assign the color.
4. Then implement `didSelectItem` method to get the click item of particular cell (or color) and fetch the data from your `dataArray` based on `indexPath.item` as index.